# Could you figure out why my code isn't working when it was working previously?

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

```
const mysql = require('mysql'); 
const connection = mysql.createConnection({ 
  host: process.env.host1,  
  user: process.env.user, 
  password: process.env.password, 
  port: process.env.port1, 
  connectionLimit: 10,   
  multipleStatements: true,
  connectionLimit: 1000,   
  connectTimeout: 60 * 60 * 1000, 
  acquireTimeout: 60 * 60 * 1000, 
  timeout: 60 * 60 * 1000, 
  debug: true 
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {  
 context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
 var post  = event;
 var query1= connection.query("SELECT * FROM ForexAssistant.users WHERE username=? OR email=?",[event.username,event.email],function(error, results){
  if(results){
   callback(null, 'Already Registered'); 
  }
  else{
   var query2 = connection.query('INSERT INTO ForexAssistant.users SET ?', post, function (error, results) {
    if (error) {   
     throw error  
    }     
   callback(null, 'Successfully Registered');  
  });
 }
});
}
```

Example Test Event:

```
{
  "username": "domi",
  "password": "123456",
  "email": "do@gmail.com"
}
```

The problem is occurring on AWS Lambda with code(above) in Runtime using Node.js.
When my test event is something that I already have as an entry in the mysql table it will give the callback Already Registered and when my test event is something new that isn't in the mysql table, I still get the callback Already Registered when instead it should be moving onto the else statement and executing that to get the callback Successfully Registered. Previously this was doing it correctly and I haven't modified the code since it was working and when I checked it last night that is when I noticed this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length of `results` also

```
if (results && results.length !== 0) {
  // ...
}
```